# How to switch words in an easy manner (in VIM)?

Tags: vim

I'm not good enough at vim to determine whether this was possible or not (which is why I came to superuser and not good) ~ is there a way in vim to easily switch two words?

for example in `def function(param1, param2)` is there a quick/easy way to change that to `def function(param2, param1)`???

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I don't remember where I originally got this, but it's been in my ~/.vimrc for at least a few years:

```
" Swap the word the cursor is on with the next word (which can be on a
" newline, and punctuation is "skipped"):
nmap <silent> gw "_yiw:s/\(\%#\w\+\)\(\_W\+\)\(\w\+\)/\3\2\1/<CR><C-o>:noh<CR>
```

After you have this defined, all you need to do is put your cursor somewhere on "param1" in normal mode and type: `gw`

Comment: I have it also, it comes from the vim wiki.

Answer (score 8):

That long solution is ugly. Suppose your cursor is at the left the first letter of the first word, that is 'p'. Do this: `dwlpldw%p`.
This fits in your special case. How about dealing with daily editing? Try `dwwP`, or `dWWP`. :D

Tips: Don't always write long regular expression, if you don't need to do this often. Otherwise your vimrc booms. All vim users shall be familiar with its builtin cursor movement.

Comment: This is the way.

Answer (score 5):

+1 for @Heptite's answer.

For more completeness, here is what I have in my .vimrc:

```
" push current line up or down
nnoremap <leader><Up> ddkP
nnoremap <leader><Down> ddp

" exchange character under cursor with the next character without moving the cursor
nnoremap gc xph

" exchange word under cursor with the next word without moving the cursor
nnoremap gw "_yiw:s/\(\%#\w\+\)\(\_W\+\)\(\w\+\)/\3\2\1/<CR><C-o><C-l>

" push word under cursor to the left
nnoremap <leader><Left> "_yiw?\w\+\_W\+\%#<CR>:s/\(\%#\w\+\)\(\_W\+\)\(\w\+\)/\3\2\1/<CR><C-o><C-l>

" push word under cursor to the right
nnoremap <leader><Right> "_yiw:s/\(\%#\w\+\)\(\_W\+\)\(\w\+\)/\3\2\1/<CR><C-o>/\w\+\_W\+<CR><C-l>
```

Source: [the vim wiki](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Swapping_characters,_words_and_lines).

I see my (and the wiki's) `gw` is slightly different from Heptite's one. I'm not sure which one is better.

Answer (score 1):

## Swap mappings for Latin languages

The swap mappings from the [Vim wiki](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Swapping_characters,_words_and_lines) will not operate correctly on **words with accented characters.**

These mappings are adapted to work with (European) [ISO/IEC_8859-1 Latin-1 Supplement characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1). This is done by substituting all instances of `\w` in the [Vim wiki code](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Swapping_characters,_words_and_lines) with `[0-9A-Za-zÀ-ÖØ-öø-ÿ_\-]` and all instances of `\_W` with `\_[^0-9A-Za-zÀ-ÖØ-öø-ÿ_\-]`.

## Clearing of search highlighting

Furthermore, [the search highlighting is cleared](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33580359/2192488) where needed.
This is achieved by adding `:nohlsearch<return>` at the end of each mapping where it is required.

Here is the end result:

```
" Use gc to swap the current CHARACTER with the next, WITHOUT changing the cursor position.
nnoremap <silent> gc xph

" Use gw to swap the current WORD with the next, WITHOUT changing the cursor position.
nnoremap <silent> gw "_yiw:s/\(\%#[0-9A-Za-zÀ-ÖØ-öø-ÿ_\-\`]\+\)\(\_[^0-9A-Za-zÀ-ÖØ-öø-ÿ_\-\`]\+\)\([0-9A-Za-zÀ-ÖØ-öø-ÿ_\-\`]\+\)/\3\2\1/<CR><c-o><c-l>:nohlsearch<return>

" Disable Alt+[menukey] menu keys (i.e. Alt+h for help)
set winaltkeys=no

" Use Alt + ← or Alt + h to swap the current WORD with the previous, keeping the cursor on the current word. This feels like "PUSHING" the word to the left.
nnoremap <silent> <A-Left> "_yiw?[0-9A-Za-zÀ-ÖØ-öø-ÿ_\-\`]\+\_[^0-9A-Za-zÀ-ÖØ-öø-ÿ_\-\`]\+\%#<CR>:s/\(\%#[0-9A-Za-zÀ-ÖØ-öø-ÿ_\-\`]\+\)\(\_[^0-9A-Za-zÀ-ÖØ-öø-ÿ_\-\`]\+\)\([0-9A-Za-zÀ-ÖØ-öø-ÿ_\-\`]\+\)/\3\2\1/<CR><c-o><c-l>:nohlsearch<return>
nnoremap <silent> <A-h>    "_yiw?[0-9A-Za-zÀ-ÖØ-öø-ÿ_\-\`]\+\_[^0-9A-Za-zÀ-ÖØ-öø-ÿ_\-\`]\+\%#<CR>:s/\(\%#[0-9A-Za-zÀ-ÖØ-öø-ÿ_\-\`]\+\)\(\_[^0-9A-Za-zÀ-ÖØ-öø-ÿ_\-\`]\+\)\([0-9A-Za-zÀ-ÖØ-öø-ÿ_\-\`]\+\)/\3\2\1/<CR><c-o><c-l>:nohlsearch<return>
" <A-h> corresponds to è

" Use Alt + → or Alt + l to swap the current WORD with the next, keeping the cursor on the current word. This feels like "PUSHING" the word to the right.
nnoremap <silent> <A-Right> "_yiw:s/\(\%#[0-9A-Za-zÀ-ÖØ-öø-ÿ_\-\`]\+\)\(\_[^0-9A-Za-zÀ-ÖØ-öø-ÿ_\-\`]\+\)\([0-9A-Za-zÀ-ÖØ-öø-ÿ_\-\`]\+\)/\3\2\1/<CR><c-o>/[0-9A-Za-zÀ-ÖØ-öø-ÿ_\-\`]\+\_[^0-9A-Za-zÀ-ÖØ-öø-ÿ_\-\`]\+<CR><c-l>:nohlsearch<return>
nnoremap <silent> <A-l>     "_yiw:s/\(\%#[0-9A-Za-zÀ-ÖØ-öø-ÿ_\-\`]\+\)\(\_[^0-9A-Za-zÀ-ÖØ-öø-ÿ_\-\`]\+\)\([0-9A-Za-zÀ-ÖØ-öø-ÿ_\-\`]\+\)/\3\2\1/<CR><c-o>/[0-9A-Za-zÀ-ÖØ-öø-ÿ_\-\`]\+\_[^0-9A-Za-zÀ-ÖØ-öø-ÿ_\-\`]\+<CR><c-l>:nohlsearch<return>
" <A-l> corresponds to ì

" Use g{ to swap the current PARAGRAPH with the next.
nnoremap g{ {dap}p{
```

Answer (score 1):

I wrote up repeatable mappings using a combination of [vim-exchange](https://github.com/tommcdo/vim-exchange), [Repeatable](https://github.com/kreskij/Repeatable.vim) (which depends on [repeat.vim](https://github.com/tpope/vim-repeat)), and [argtextobj](https://github.com/vim-scripts/argtextobj.vim).

```
" Swap function arguments, move the argument under the cursor to the left or to
" the right.
Repeatable map <leader>al cxiaf,cxia
Repeatable map <leader>ah cxiaF,hcxia
```

The advantage in using the exchange and repeatable plugins for these mappings are:

- Doing one undo `u` will undo the swap (they're atomic changes)
- You can use the `.` to keep moving the argument left/right.

I know I know, it seems like a whole lot of plugins for a simple operation, but think what **else** those plugins give you:

- argtextobj gives you the `ia` and `aa` textobj for deleting (`dia` and `daa`), and yanking (`yia`).
- vim-repeat and Repeatable for making any of your mappings repeatable with `.`.
- vim-exchange gives you repeatable, atomic exchanging of text.

Answer (score 0):

[Eclim](https://github.com/ervandew/eclim) plugin provides a good one. All credits to them :)

```
:SwapWords
```

.. and if you don't want to install the whole plugin, here is their function extracted:

```
" Swap words:
" taken from Eclim
" https://github.com/ervandew/eclim

function! SwapWords() " {{{
  " Initially based on http://www.vim.org/tips/tip.php?tip_id=329

  " save the last search pattern
  let save_search = @/

  normal! "_yiw
  let pos = getpos('.')
  keepjumps s/\(\%#\w\+\)\(\_W\+\)\(\w\+\)/\3\2\1/
  call setpos('.', pos)

  " restore the last search pattern
  let @/ = save_search

  silent! call repeat#set(":call SwapWords()\<cr>", v:count)
endfunction " }}}

command! SwapWords :call SwapWords()
```